# How to install Github NuGet Packages?

Tags: .net, github, nuget

I want to install this: https://github.com/Dewera/Lunar
in a project on my local computer,but I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet package related to this repository is located here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lunar-RPatch/
You can install it from Visual Studio by using the NuGet Package Manager.

If you do not use Visual Studio, you can use .NET CLI and install it by using this:

```
dotnet add package Lunar-RPatch --version 1.1.0
```

Good luck!